# How to invert exit code for any Bash utility

Tags: bash, exit-code

How can exit codes of a program be inverted through Bash such that when it exits with a 0 exit code, I get a 1, otherwise a 0?

Comment: `0 exit code, I get a 1` --> meaning you want to make a command fail when it passes. Remember `0` in shell's context is successful execution. You need to provide more details

Comment: @Inian Exactly. I want to make a command fail when it passes and pass when it fails.

Comment: Kind of like a not operation on the exit code

Comment: TL;DR: Use !. `! my_program`.